Lumen return Double values as string in Json
I'm using Lumen framework with a MySQL database.
I have two columns in my clients table:

name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
nb_part DOUBLE NOT NULL

I have one line in my table:

John ; 1.00

When I return this item I got this JSON:
{
  name: "John",
  nb_part: "1.00"
}

I return data like that:
$client = Client::select('clients.name', 'clients.nb_part')
            ->where('clients.id', $id) // $id is input parameter
            ->first();
            
return response()->json($client, 200);

Why nb_part is quoted ?

It's probably during the Select operation, I'd guess it's pulling the data out as a string? Check the data types in $client, before it gets JSON encoded. Regular json_encode in PHP won't convert a number to a string like that.
